# How can I write $_{\text{s}}$ in a bookmark?

Tags: unicode, bookmarks

I need to write `$E_{\text{s}}$` in a pdf-bookmark, but

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
%209B ;LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER S;Lm;0;L;<sub> 0073;;;;N;;;;;
\DeclareTextCommand{\textsinferior}{PU}{\9040\233}%
\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{$E_{\text{s}}$}{E\textsinferior}}
\end{document}
```

gives [image: bookmark] as bookmark (at least in Adobe Reader 10.1.3 and Sumatra, both @ Win XP) and no error in the `log`-file. What is my mistake, and how is it done right?

I have placed the pdf at https://www.zeta-uploader.com/1675640013 (link will rot at 2012/06/19).

Edit: As was confirmed by tests performed by fellow tex.SE users (thanks!), on some systems the pdf displays all right, on other systems it does not. Thus this is a viewer/os/installed fonts/... issue and not a TeX one. Sorry to have bothered you & thanks for testing (`.tex` as well as `.pdf`).

Comment: It seems to be pdf-reader dependent. I have no problem with the bookmark in either Evince or Okular on Linux. What version of Adobe Reader do you use?

Comment: Using Adobe reader X I have no problems at all.

Comment: I concur with @aagaard: the font used by Adobe Reader must have the character in order to show it. On my machine it shows indeed a (very tiny) "subscript s".

Comment: @egreg: Could you please check whether my pdf is OK? [https://www.zeta-uploader.com/1675640013](https://www.zeta-uploader.com/1675640013) If it is, it's not TeX-related at all but some font problem on this PC.

Comment: @Stephen It shows exactly like my test.

Comment: @Stephen I can reproduce the error with Acroread X on Windows. I recently had a similar issue with a `\mathbb` symbol which the `unicode` option couldn't resolve. `fixltx2e's` `\textsubscript{s}` doesn't produce the box, but changes the subscript to a standard lowercase s. By the way, I remember having read about directly editing the bookmarks file in the hyperref manual, maybe that'd be worth a try.

Comment: @dgs: In the `.out` file there is `\040\233` for `\textsinferior`, thus that seems to be OK. When the file is only displayed in a wrong way depending on reader/operation system/installed fonts/whatsoever, I conclude that the problem is no TeX issue. I'll search for information about how to edit the bookmarks file, but vote to close this question as too localized/not a TeX issue. (If somebody does find a solution nevertheless, it would be nice to post it as comment.)

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for testing! At least the pdf is ok, now I just need a new PC to display it correctly... ;-)